# Non-relational database schema for Django with postgres

Tags: json, django, mongodb, postgresql, non-relational-database

My Django project uses postgresql 9.4, which supports JSON fields. I would like to switch from a relational to a (partly) non-relational schema using these fields.

Say I have models `Foo` and `Bar` and each object `Bar` belongs to exactly one `Foo`. Currently, I use a ForeignKey from `Bar` to `Foo` to model this, but I would like to switch to storing the `Bar` objects directly inside `Foo` as a list of model instances. With postgresql, I can use a `JSONField` in `Foo` which would store a list of JSON representations of `Bar` objects, but then I would have to deal with serialization to JSON manually.

The MongoDB ORM for Django provides the Django fields to do that in a clean way:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar_list = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Bar'))
```

Is there a way to have a similar functionality with the postgres backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting data objects within each other is a very Non-relational database approach that is not recommended and is going to cause performance issues in a relational database.

You will have a few problems if you try this in postgres:

1. Your querying abilities on the nested JSON data will be limited to text only.
2. Forget about sorting, aggregation and such for the nested data.
3. You will have to deal with serialization when you need the nested data and before you send back to the database to save.
4. Making changes to the nested models will become very python heavy since you're basically circumventing all the good integrity checks that relational databases have and the nice checks that Django has for types and such.
5. Querying will become slower because you will have to retrieve every nested object for every Foo you query since there isn't a way to limit the amount of nested objects like you can in Mongo.

The recommendation here is to stick with one database type Relational or Non-relational and do what works good on either one.

If you need Postgres use Foreign keys and if you use Mongo use nested objects.

Comment: Thanks, but I have been playing with the data for a few years now, I know the queries I run on it, and I am pretty sure I need this refactoring to speed things up (1. I don't query the nested objects. 2. I don't need this. 3. this should be handled by the ORM 4. changes to these models are already python heavy 5. there are few nested objects, the average number of Bar objects in a Foo is close to one).

Comment: I see you took it the wrong way. I'm not questioning your knowledge of data I'm just giving you what I have experienced before and the drawbacks to this approach.

Since you absolutely need this you might be able to use the JSONField available since Django 1.9. It receives a Python object and saves it as JSON, when it's retrieved get's parsed to Python once again.

Comment: Yes, that's also what I was mentioning in my question, I just wondered whether there existed a more high-level version of that. Apparently there isn't, so that answers the question. :-)